# WPF User Control Data Binding Not Working

Tags: wpf, vb.net, data-binding, user-controls, wpf-controls

I'm creating a simple User Control combining a popup with a text view, nothing crazy. When I set it up in a window at first to style it all out, it worked perfectly, but when I moved it into a User Control to actually finish it up, it won't work correctly any more.

I pass a min and max value into the control and then it automatically creates a list of numbers to pick from in that range. In the User Control, the list of numbers doesn't get bound correctly, who knows why. Maybe someone can take a look at my code.

I've read a bunch of other questions about this, but don't really know what's happening. I'm not getting any errors in my output window, so no clues there. Anyway, here's the code -

UserControl.xaml

```
<UserControl x:Class="UserControl1"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         x:Name="Me"
         DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">

<StackPanel>
    <TextBox Name="myTextbox"
             Height="30"
             Margin="0"
             FontSize="14"
             IsReadOnly="True"
             Padding="5,2"
             Text="{Binding Value}" />
    <Popup x:Name="myPopup"
           PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=myTextbox}"
           StaysOpen="True">
        <Popup.Style>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type Popup}">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=myTextbox, Path=IsFocused}" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="IsOpen" Value="True" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </Popup.Style>

        <StackPanel>
            <ListView Name="myListView"
                      Height="100"
                      MaxHeight="300"
                      ItemsSource="{Binding List,
                                            UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                      SelectionChanged="ListView_SelectionChanged">
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Label Width="100"
                               Height="30"
                               Margin="0"
                               Content="{Binding}"
                               FontFamily="Segoe UI"
                               FontSize="14"
                               Padding="5,2" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
            <Button Width="200" Height="30" />
        </StackPanel>
    </Popup>

</StackPanel>
```

UserControl.xaml.vb

```
Imports System.ComponentModel
Imports System.Linq.Expressions
Imports System.Collections.ObjectModel

Class UserControl1

' Dependency Properties
Public Shared ReadOnly ListProperty As DependencyProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("List", GetType(ObservableCollection(Of Integer)), GetType(MainWindow))
Public Shared ReadOnly ValueProperty As DependencyProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Value", GetType(Integer), GetType(MainWindow))
Public Shared ReadOnly MaxValueProperty As DependencyProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("MaxValue", GetType(Integer), GetType(MainWindow))
Public Shared ReadOnly MinValueProperty As DependencyProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("MinValue", GetType(Integer), GetType(MainWindow))

' Properties
Public Property List As ObservableCollection(Of Integer)
    Get
        Return DirectCast(GetValue(ListProperty), ObservableCollection(Of Integer))
    End Get
    Set(value As ObservableCollection(Of Integer))
        SetValue(ListProperty, value)
    End Set
End Property

Public Property Value As Integer
    Get
        Return DirectCast(GetValue(ValueProperty), Integer)
    End Get
    Set(value As Integer)
        SetValue(ValueProperty, value)

    End Set
End Property

Public Property MaxValue As Integer
    Get
        Return DirectCast(GetValue(MaxValueProperty), Integer)
    End Get
    Set(value As Integer)
        SetValue(MaxValueProperty, value)
    End Set
End Property

Public Property MinValue As Integer
    Get
        Return DirectCast(GetValue(MinValueProperty), Integer)
    End Get
    Set(value As Integer)
        SetValue(MinValueProperty, value)
    End Set
End Property

Private Sub ListView_SelectionChanged(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.Controls.SelectionChangedEventArgs)
    Value = List(myListView.SelectedIndex)
End Sub

Private Sub UserControl1_Loaded(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs) Handles Me.Loaded
    List = New ObservableCollection(Of Integer)

    ' Add all available numbers into the list
    For iCounter As Integer = MinValue To MaxValue
        List.Add(iCounter)
    Next

    ' Set the selected index on the list for the value
    myListView.SelectedIndex = Value - MinValue
End Sub
End Class
```

Just for reference, when I tested this out, I set the Min and Max values myself in both the window and usercontrol setup.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I think that you have made the same mistake that I used to when I first started learning WPF. I can't guarantee that this *is* the cause of your problem, but as it's the only one that I can see, I'll address it. Unfortunately, there are so many poor tutorials and quick examples that show the connecting of a `UserControl.DataContext` to itself:

```
DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
```

Or:

```
DataContext = this;
```

Now this is perfectly acceptable if you *don't* want to `Bind` to the `UserControl` externally because it's a quick and easy way to connect with properties defined in the code behind. However, when you want to `Bind` to the properties from outside the control, you'll find problems. In these instances (if not on all occasions), you should use a `RelativeSource Binding` to `Bind` to your code behind properties:

```
<TextBox Name="myTextbox" Height="30" Margin="0" FontSize="14" IsReadOnly="True"
    Padding="5,2" Text="{Binding Value, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={
    x:Type UserControl1}}}" />
```

In this `Binding`, `UserControl1` is the name of the `UserControl` that declared the properties. This should be done on all of the internal `Binding`s. This way, the `DataContext` is *not* set to the `UserControl`, but the `Binding`s still find the properties.

You can find out more about `RelativeSource` from the [RelativeSource MarkupExtension](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743599.aspx) page on MSDN.

Answer (score 9):

As I cant provide a comment to Sheridan good answer I have to provide a new answer, sorry for this.

While I love this solution

```
DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
```

it fails (as Sheridan pointed out already) fast.

What you can do is just set the DataContext of the content of your User Control

```
<UserControl x:Class="Example.View.Controls.MyUserControl"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
         xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:Example.View.Controls"
         mc:Ignorable="d">
<Grid DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type controls:MyUserControl}}}">

</Grid>
```

In this way all following Bindings have less Boilerplate code as you can just bind directly to your DP from the code-behind like:

```
<Label Content="{Binding MyLabel}"/>
```

Comment: Thanks. The same problem exists and this woks in c# as well

Answer (score 1):

As for **Windows Apps (Windows 8 and Windows 10 UWP)** the way to go is to give your control a name and reference it within your XAML file using **Path** and **ElementName**:

```
<UserControl
x:Class="MyControl"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
x:Name="Control"
mc:Ignorable="d" >

   <Grid Height="240" VerticalAlignment="Top">
     <Rectangle Fill="{Binding ElementName=Control, Path=Background}" />
   </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

``