# How to binding a Command in Style in .xaml from .cs?

Tags: c#, wpf, button, command

Now, I'm mocking up the MessageBox. I build the `Close Button` in Style.Template in .xaml, but I don't know how to binding the command with CloseCommand. Whether it can bingding with **System Close Command**?

.cs (define a custom control):

```
internal sealed class MessageBoxModule : Window
{
    #region Constructor
    static MessageBoxModule()
    {
        DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(
            typeof(MessageBoxModule),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(MessageBoxModule)));
    }

    public MessageBoxModule()
    {
        WindowStartupLocation = System.Windows.WindowStartupLocation.CenterScreen;
        AllowsTransparency = true;
        WindowStyle = System.Windows.WindowStyle.None;
        ShowInTaskbar = false;

        try
        {
            Resources.Source = new Uri(@"/Wpf.Controls;component/Themes/Generic.xaml", UriKind.Relative);
        }
        catch
        { }
...
```

.xaml (is a ResourceDictionary file, provide a style for MessageBoxModule):

```
<ResourceDictionary 
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Wpf.Controls">
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type local:MessageBoxModule}">
            <Setter Property="Template" >
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:MessageBoxModule}">
                        <Border ...>
                            <Button x:Name="CloseButton".../>
                            ...
                        </Border>
...
```

see the **red button**, I don't know how to binding a command for it:

[image]

This is **The Entire solution:**

.cs:

```
internal sealed class MessageBoxModule : Window
{
    public MessageBoxModule()
    {
        InputGestureCollection inputGestures = new InputGestureCollection();
        inputGestures.Add(new KeyGesture(Key.F4, ModifierKeys.Alt));
        CloseCommand = new RoutedCommand(
            "CloseCommand",
            typeof(MessageBoxModule),
            inputGestures);
        CommandBindings.Add(new CommandBinding(CloseCommand, CloseCommandExecuted));
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty CloseCommandProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(
            "CloseCommand", 
            typeof(RoutedCommand), 
            typeof(MessageBoxModule));

    public RoutedCommand CloseCommand
    {
        get { return (RoutedCommand)GetValue(CloseCommandProperty); }
        set { SetValue(CloseCommandProperty, value); }
    }

    public void CloseCommandExecuted(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Close();
    }
}
```

.xaml:

```
<ResourceDictionary >
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type local:MessageBoxModule}">
        <Setter Property="Template" >
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:MessageBoxModule}">
                    <Border ...>
                        <Button x:Name="CloseButton" Command="{TemplateBinding CloseCommand}"/>
...
```

Comment: Post relevant code please.

Comment: If you use MVVM pattern you can simply achieve that .

Comment: @Binson Eldhose Yes, I ues MVVM pattern, how can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Expose `dependency property` of type `ICommand` from class `MessageBoxModule`:

```
public ICommand CloseCommand
{
   get { return (ICommand)GetValue(CloseCommandProperty); }
   set { SetValue(CloseCommandProperty, value); }
}

public static readonly DependencyProperty CloseCommandProperty =
   DependencyProperty.Register("CloseCommand", typeof(ICommand), 
                                typeof(MessageBoxModule));
```

Use `TemplateBinding` to bind to Command like this:

```
<Button x:Name="CloseButton" Command="{TemplateBinding CloseCommand}"/>
```

Since command is exposed, you can bind to it from outside like this:

```
<local:MessageBoxModule CloseCommand="{Binding ViewModelCommand}"/>
```

***Assuming you already have View model in place and it already contains ICommand to which you want to bind close button.***

Comment: Great. No problem.. :)

Comment: um..I think MessageBoxModule is a very simple Window with simple functions, so I don't provide a view model for it. I have post the entire solution, reference here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13035551/how-to-use-command-bindings-in-user-controls-in-wpf

Comment: Yeah in case you want to close it via shortcut `Alt+F4`, key command bindings is a way to do. :)

Answer (score 0):

@SubmarineX

Create a DataContext for the button  Something like

```
public class ButtonViewModel{

private RelayCommand _CloseCommand;

public ICommand CloseCommand
        {
            get { return _CloseCommand?? (_CloseCommand= new RelayCommand(p => Close())); }
        }

void Close(){

//Here u cn write the  logic which close the window from this view model or  raise an event which handled by your button container

}
}


    public class RelayCommand : ICommand
    {
        #region Fields

        private readonly Action<object> _execute;
        private readonly Predicate<object> _canExecute;

        #endregion // Fields

        #region Constructors

        public RelayCommand(Action<object> execute)
            : this(execute, null)
        {
        }

        public RelayCommand(Action<object> execute, Predicate<object> canExecute)
        {
            if (execute == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("execute");
            _execute = execute;
            _canExecute = canExecute;
        }

        #endregion // Constructors

        #region ICommand Members [DebuggerStepThrough]

        public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
        {
            return _canExecute == null || _canExecute(parameter);
        }

        public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
        {
            add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
            remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }
        }

        public void Execute(object parameter)
        {
            _execute(parameter);
        }

        #endregion // ICommand Members }
    }
```

in xaml

```
<Button x:Name="CloseButton" Command="{Binding Close}"/>
```

Ensure that the DataContext is availble for the button